# Size of characters in *argv[] when passed argument from command line

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, char

I have simple program.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); ++i)
        printf("%x ", argv[1][i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I run it like

```sh
$ ./program 111
31 31 31
```

But when I run it like

```sh
$ ./program ●●●
ffffffe2 ffffff97 ffffff8f ffffffe2 ffffff97 ffffff8f ffffffe2 ffffff97 ffffff8f
```

Here each `●` is should be encoded by 3 bytes (UTF-8): `e2` `97` `8f`, but looks like it is encoded by 3 `unsigned`.
I don't understand where the `ffffff` comes from if `sizeof(char)` is always 1 byte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf()` is a function accepting a variable number of arguments.

Any integer argument of a type shorter than `int` is automatically converted to type `int`.

Apparently, in your implementation, the "character" `little-round-thing` is composed of `3` `char`s, all with a negative value.

Try these

```
printf("%x ", (unsigned char)argv[1][i]);
printf("%hhx ", argv[1][i]); // thanks to Jonathan Leffler
```

Comment: Rather, on his implementation, `char` has a sign, and all multi-codeunit codepoints only contain codeunits >127, thus negative on 8bit 2s-complement.

Comment: @Deduplicator: you mean `strlen("little-round-thing") == 3` means `1` multi-codeunit codepoint or `3` characters? I changed my answer :)

Comment: yes, but that's not really the important part.

Comment: Or `%hhx`as the conversion specification.

Comment: Or `#include <inttypes.h>` and `printf ("%" PRIx8 " ", (uint8_t)argv[1][i]);` using exact-width types.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand where the ffffff comes from if sizeof(char) is always 1 byte.

by definition `sizeof(char)` is 1, but '●' is not a *char* in the C sense and produces 3 *char*

your char are visibly signed (a *char* is a *signed char* by default in your case), each the input ● produce each 3 negative codes, because your *char* is converted to an *int* (32b in your case) and the format `%x` consider the argument unsigned you have these output

you will have the same output doing `printf("%x", -30);` -> ffffffe2

---

note to do `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); ++i)` is expensive for nothing, the length doesn't change, better to save it or to just do `for (int i = 0; argv[1][i] != 0; ++i)`

it was also better to check *argc* is at least 1 before to look into `argv[1]`

Comment: Thansk for valuable advice.

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 codeunits for multi-codeunit codepoints (everything but ASCII) are all from 128 to 255, meaning outside the ASCII range.

`printf()` is a vararg function, and all the arguments passed to the vararg part (all but the format-string) are subject to the standard promotions.

As your implementation's bare `char` is 8bit signed 2s-complement, meaning the UTF-8 codeunit-value is negative, and between `-1` and `-128`, after promotion you have an `int` with that value.

Then *you lie* to `printf()` by asserting it's an `unsigned` (`%x` is for `unsigned int`), and 2s-complement results in your *Undefined Behavior* printing a very big `unsigned int`.

You could get the right result by using `%hhx`, though strictly speaking you should cast the argument to `unsigned char`.